# Docker cant build docker image using Dockerfile, no such file or directory(Despite Dockerfile existing, and spelled correctly without extensions)

Tags: docker

I'm new to docker. I decided to use a docker container for my fastAPI app.
The command

`docker build -t image .`

throws the error

`unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /var/lib/snapd/void/Dockerfile: no such file or directory`

There is a Dockerfile in my directory and yes it is spelled "Dockerfile" with no extensions.

I tried to follow the tutorial in [Docker Docs](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/)
It encounters the same error.

My docker Installation is Fine(I run a redis container for another project).
Problem arises only while building images with Dockerfile.

Docker Version: 19.03.11, build dd360c7

OS: Ubuntu 20.04

This is the contents of the Dockerfile.

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.7

COPY ./app /app
```

UPDATE: My PC has a windows OS as well, the same commands are working in Windows(Hence it's not an issue of misnamed/missing Docker**f**ile)

Comment: is your  Dockerfile path a symlink?

Comment: How can I know if it's a symlink @elonzh

Comment: try `ls -l`, it will have a `->` point the real path if it is a symlink

Answer (score 0):

**This message shows up when `docker build` can't find your Dockerfile.**

Please make sure:

- There is a Dockerfile in the folder from where you run `docker build`.
- Your Dockerfile is named *Dockerfile*, not *Docker**F**ile*.
- Your Dockerfile has no extension, e.g. *Dockerfile.txt*